# Speed up a vba macro to import xml data into an excel workbook while deleting connections and xmlmaps

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I currently import 12000+ xml files into an excel workbook using the following vba:

```
Public Sub XMLIMport()

    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim strXML As String
    Dim ct As Integer, XMLMap

    Const maxXMLDel = 1
    lngRow = 2

    Do While Cells(lngRow, 1) <> ""
        strXML = Cells(lngRow, 1)
        ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:=strXML, _
        ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=False, _
        Destination:=Range("$B$" & lngRow)
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        For Each XMLMap In ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps
                  XMLMap.Delete
        Next
    Loop

End Sub
```

and then proceed to import the workbook sheet from excel into a table in access 2007. The import uses links to the server to download the individual files.

So in column A is the xml link and the macro places the xml data results in columns B, C, D, etc and proceeds to the next row and repeats the process for each file. But with so many files it takes quite some time before the process is finished. I have even included deleting xml maps to speed up the process, but Excel 2007 still takes quite awhile to finish the process (2hrs+).

Is this macro I guess for lack of a better word 'optimized' for what I am wanting or is there another way this should be done?

UPDATE: disabled screen updating but running into an error trying to delete the connections.

running the macro recorder I get the following for deleting some of the connections, but I am unsure how to add this to the above macro to make it delete the connection in addition to the xmlmap before proceeding to the next file.

```
Sub deleteconnection()
'
' deleteconnection Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse1").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse10").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse100").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse101").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse102").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse103").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse104").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse105").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse106").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse107").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse108").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse109").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse11").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse110").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse111").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse112").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse113").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse114").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse115").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse116").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse117").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse118").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("itemResponse119").Delete

End Sub
```

EDIT: Trying to adding a deletion for connections using the following

```
Public Sub XMLIMport()

    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim strXML As String
    Dim ct As Integer, XMLMap
    Dim QTable As QueryTables


    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Const maxXMLDel = 1
    lngRow = 2

    Do While Cells(lngRow, 1) <> ""
        strXML = Cells(lngRow, 1)
        ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:=strXML, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=False, Destination:=Range("$B$" & lngRow)
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        For Each XMLMap In ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps
                  XMLMap.Delete
         Next
         For Each QTable In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
                  QTable.Delete

         Next
    Loop

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

results in the connections being still left in the workbook and the first file is reinserted

Comment: Standard advice, but have you tried turning off screenupdating and setting calculation to manual?

Comment: What does your XML look like: can you include an example?

Comment: setting it to manual and turning off screenupdating speeds it up some, but I am assuming that with that many files I also have that many connections which need to be deleted.

Comment: One question is how long does it take just to download 12000 XML files...  I'm guessing that's going to take some time just by itself.

Comment: well once disable screen updating and timed the macro for 5 minutes I was able to get through the first 900 so that does speed it up immensely, but I also had to manually go and delete the connections which does not currently happen in the macro

Comment: Likely you can use the same kind of loop as you use for deleting the XmlMaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all connections:

```
Dim Conn As Object        '* connection collection

For Each Conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections

    Conn.Delete

Next Conn
```

Comment: So how is this added to the existing macro so that everything is taking place all at once? Or are you saying to do this separately as I am doing currently?

Comment: couldn't get it added to the above macro but it does delete the connections.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance of slow XMLmap Import for large tables resize the ListObject's Range BEFORE the import.

From 60 secs for importing 60'000 records x 10 fields

```
lst.XmlMap.Import "c:\data\dummy.xml"
```

to below 5 secs for this:

```
lst.Resize lst.Range.Resize(data.count)
lst.XmlMap.Import "c:\data\dummy.xml"
```

So it really pays to get the items count before import. I assume the performance gap is due to excel inserting each row separately during import. Possibly you have the row count already else you can use SelectNodes(x).length in a DomDocument. Or use element(x).Descendents(y).Count...